# Защита приложения от fake gps

Tags: objective-c, android

День добрый Меня интересует как Можно защититься от файк GPS на ios и android?

Comment: А что такое Fake GPS?

Comment: Плюсую предыдущему комментарию

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть у Андроида такая возможность - выдавать подложные gps координаты (с помощью ddms). ТС намекает на приложение [fake gps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en).

Бороться конечно же можно. Например, простым способом - человек обычно не может перемещаться очень быстро. Поэтому, запоминаем несколько последних координат и время и просто проверяем "скорость перемещения". Заодно, и [телепортеров](http://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/220589/) выловим.

Второй способ заключается в том, что реальный сигнал "болтается", координаты постоянно изменяются. А вот подложные координаты скорее всего будут одни и те же.

Третий способ, более изощеренный, заключается в том, что бы отслеживать побочные продукты изменения координат. К примеру, если координаты принадлежат Австралии (плюс-минус), а часовой пояс - Мексике... значит что то здесь не то. Конечно, большую точность здесь не нужно - можно просто сверять текущий меридиан и часовой пояс.

Comment: не знаю, что такое "валирующаяся скорость". Исправьтесь. или удалите свайп.

Comment: @KoVadim Я имел ввиду что как раз по поводу подмены Lat Lon говорили когда, прояснилось что на iOS есть такое "приложение" которое подменяет коодрионаты при этом оно проходит путь от и до точки, со скоростью скажем 100 - 120км/час. (не фиксированная скорость). И меня интересовало как от такого защититься... =)

Comment: то, что скорость будет 100 км/ч, ещё ничего не значит. Попробуйте построить график, когда Вы будете прогуливаться по тропинке с заведомо  известной траекторией. Вы увидите, что оно не ровное, а постоянно болтается вокруг заданной линии (5-10 метров). И это при хорошем качестве сигнала и безхмарном небе. А вот такие программы, которые симулируют координаты, скорее всего ведут "ровно".
Замечу, что это дрожание абсолютно не зависит от того, айось это или андроид.

Answer (score 1):

А может ли приложение получить сырой поток данных GPS-модуля, например, в NMEA-формате? Если да, то эвристики на базе правдоподобности этого потока в плане, например, принимаемых спутников или эфемерид будут решать задачу выявления читтеров более надёжно. К тому же бан должен наступать не мгновенно, а после накопления некоторого объёма компрометирующих данных. Это усложнит реверс-инженеринг логики работы эвристик, которые, к слову, следует размещать на сервере, а не на клиенте.
Против лома нет приёма, однако, лом в наши дни не редкость. Гауссовский шум против выше изложенного метода научится подмешивать к координатам каждый первый апплет, предназначенный для подделки координат. Это как война спамеров с антиспам-фильтрами -- она вечна, а меньшие потери будет нести тот, кто построит более удобную и гибкую инфраструктуру обеспечения изменчивости своих средств защиты/нападения. Защиту всегда можно сделать эффективнее нападения, если правильно подойти к решению проблемы.

Дополню, что от эвристик, связанных с проверкой средней скорости за последнее время и анализом шумовой составляющей потока координат я отказываться не предлагаю. Просто этого будет недостаточно в долгосрочной перспективе.